# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split') is the error i got while deploying my chrome extension

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascript and this is my first code challenge. after writing a chrome extension i am trying to deploy the chrome extension but i am getting the error above and the extension is not working properly accordingly to the functionality of the extension. Here are the codes

```
    function getURL(){

    return window.location.href

    }

    const mainEL = document.getElementById("main")


    const eL=document.getElementById("caption")


    const saveEL=document.getElementById("save")

    const topKeys=['FRED','SAM','PER','CRAFT','MARK','SANDRA','DERICK'];

    const searchKeys=['RITA','PER','DERICK','FRED','BEN','ZOEY'];

    const urlString = getURL();

    const search2=new URL(urlString).searchParams.get("q").split(" ");

    const found=String(search2).toUpperCase().split(",").filter((val)=>{return 
    searchKeys.includes(val)});

    const isFound=topKeys.some(ai=>found.includes(ai));


    function noMatch(){

     for(i of found){

    eL.innerHTML+=[i]+', '
     }
    }


    function topMatch(){

    eL.innerHTML="<a href='#'>there is a match</a>"
    }

    if(found.length>0&&isFound===true){

    topMatch()

     }else if(found.length>0&&isFound===false){

    noMatch()
    }
```

Comment: Is "String" a function you wrote? Otherwise, did you mean to use search2.toString() ?

Comment: I think when you does not get `q` in param it gives null and you can't call split on null. So just pass default value by using `.?` and `||` if `q` is absent. like `new URL(urlString).searchParams.get("q")?.split(" ") || '';`